# duda consultas mysqli vs poo consultas preparadas

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

Tengo varios meses trabajando con el driver *mysqli* pero me ha surgido una inquietud mas que una pregunta es una duda, quisiera obtener opiniones de espertos en este tema  la cosa es que siempre que hago consultas a la bd ya sea para insertar o lo que sea siempre hago lo siguiente ejemplo:

```
$id=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_GET["id"]);
```

y luego

```
$sql=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM contenido WHERE id='$id' ");
```

**DUDA:** ¿Ésto es vulnerable a ataques sql? o deberia usar consultas preparadas?

La cosa es que estoy muy adaptado al driver mysqli me manejo muy bien con el pero estoy por cambiar al estilo orientado a objetos `->` **Nota:** no me gusta PDO.

¿Qué me recomiendan y cual sería mejor y por qué? Gracias de ante mano chicos .

Comment: [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php/18233#18233) tienes información sobre el tema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Aunque mysqli corrigió errores del driver anterior; tu consulta sigue
>   sin ser consulta preparada dado lo cual si sería vulnerable a ataques
>   de inyección SQL; tal como la colocas, te muestro como debería quedar

```
$sql=$conexion->prepare($conexion,"SELECT * FROM contenido WHERE id=? ");
$sql->bind_param("i", $id);
$sql->execute();
```

Opcionalmente puedes dejar la llegada del id con tu siguiente consulta

```
$id=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_GET["id"]);
```

**ACERCA DE LAS CONSULTAS PREPARADAS**

Pero conviene que incluyas en tu consulta que en vez de ejecutarla directamente primero accedas al método prepare y en lugar de pasar la variable de forma directa le coloques un marcador de posición con el símbolo de ?, después con el método bin_param() logras por ejemplo que se identifique el tipo de dato que te va a llegar en el parámetro, en este caso es un id debe ser un entero ya que con ello también previenes que se trate de inyectar un valor que no corresponde; finalmente cuando el valor del marcador de posición se intercambia por el del método bind_param solo si el tipo de dato corresponde se llegará a la línea que dice execute() para procesar dicha consulta

**DEBERÍA SEGUIR CON MYSQLI??**

> Puedes seguir trabajando con el mismo, sin embargo siempre incluye la
>   estructura de las consultas preparadas, para darle mayor seguridad a
>   tu desarrollo en la parte de SQL, se recomienda en ocasiones PDO por ventajas como por ejemplo el acceso de conexión a múltiples gestores de bases de datos

**ACERCA DE mysqli_real_escape_string**

Aunque según página de PHP

*mysqli::real_escape_string -- mysqli_real_escape_string — Escapa los caracteres especiales de una cadena para usarla en una sentencia SQL, tomando en cuenta el conjunto de caracteres actual de la conexión*

Existe el riesgo de seguridad por:

*El conjunto de caracteres debe ser establecido a nivel del servidor, o con la función mysqli_set_charset() de la API para que afecte a mysqli_real_escape_string(). Véase la sección de conceptos sobre conjuntos de caracteres para más información.*

[Aqui mas info](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Si se desea trabajar la misma sentencia a nivel de PDO; la forma sería la siguiente

Ahora en vez de utilizar un marcador de posición con el símbolo de ?, usamos el marcador de nombre; de este modo `:nombrevalor`

Para poder indicar que tipo de valor debe recibir la consulta hacemos uso de `PDO::PARAM_INT` así podemos establecer el tipo de dato que se debe recibir

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
$query = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM contenido WHRERE id = :id");
$query->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
```

> **Recomendación final usa PDO**

Comment: interesante tu respuesta @Alfredo paz  y la forma orientada a objetos no tiene conexión a múltiples gestores de bases de datos?

Comment: no, mysqli esta limitado solo a mysql; si quieres otro gestor deberás usar PDO @chosen

Comment: @entiendo pero si dejo atras mysqli y solo uso la forma orientada a objetos por ejemplo estas sentencias que pusite de ejemplos no usan el driver mysqli `$sql=$conexion->prepare($conexion,"SELECT * FROM contenido WHERE id=? ");
$sql->bind_param("i", $id);
$sql->execute();` o si?

Comment: si gustas mejor te pongo un ejemplo para PDO @chosen para que compares

Comment: si claro todo por la seguridad XD lo que pasa es que estoy creando un proyecto y no siento que mysqli sea seguro pues

Comment: hecho @chosen ..

Comment: genial @Alfredo paz so seria recomendable cambiar a PDO por que en un futuro si quisiera suvir mi projecto a un servidor remoto hay mas oprtunidades con PDO correcto?

Comment: así es @chosen ...

Comment: vale gracias @Alfredo Paz ya sali de dudas Exitos!

Answer (score 1):

1- A nivel de seguridad es mucho mejor usar PDO,usas sentencias preparadas lo que reduce el riesgo de inyeccion sql.

2- es adaptable a varias Base de Datos, oracle, postgreSQL, sql en fin

3- creo que mysqlli es parte del pasado y por norma ya no se deberia usar.

la unica desventaja es que el rendimiento baja pero es casi insignificante a lo que se gana.

Comment: El punto 3 de tu respuesta no es correcto. mysqli no es parte del pasado, lo confundes con la API `mysql_*` que sí está obsoleta. mysqli es totalmente seguro si se usa correctamente, aunque como ya se ha dicho, PDO tiene algunas ventajas con respecto a mysqli.

Comment: Pero porque vas a caminar  si puedes usar un ford mustang?

Comment: No es justa la comparación: no hay tanta diferencia entre PDO y  mysqli. Te habla uno que prefiere PDO por la facilidad de cambiar de manejador de base de datos de forma casi imperceptible y por la practicidad de ciertos métodos. Pero decir que usar mysqli es ir a pie no me parece justo. Bueno, caminar también es bueno para la salud. Por cierto, no editaste el punto 3. Lo que afirmas ahí es `FALSE`.